# I think I fell for a phishing scam, but I don't feel like I gave them that much info. Should I be worried?

Tags: scam

I received a call from an "uknown caller" which I picked up. The said they were from the Border Control (of the USA where I live) informing me that there were packages at the border with illegal substances under my name, and they called me by last name. At this point fear took over (and caution left the room) so I cooperated. They gave a fake name, badge number, and case ID number, so I was convinced, even though the circumstances were obviously suspicious.

They began by telling me a couple addresses that were supposedly under my name in a state far from where I live, and asked for my **ZIP code**, which I provided. Then they said that there were accounts opened with a bunch of banks under my name, and that if I didn't recognize them they would be blocked. They asked **if I had an account with any of them**, and I told them I did.

They stressed that they would not ask for any passwords or anything like that. Then they asked me **roughly how much I had in my account** so they could "identify" it and I guess not block that one? I gave an estimate like "between X and Y thousand dollars." They also asked me if I had any

- **property,**
- **credit cards,**
- or **crypto accounts**

under my name, to which I answered all honestly, without providing any sort of information beyond the existence/nonexistence thereof. They also asked me **if I had any cash** and then finally **if I had a car** under my name, and then hung up abruptly, at which point I realized I had probably been scammed. I assume now that if it had been real, they would have simply arrested me at my house rather than calling, and the name they gave belongs to someone in the government who would certainly not be calling me like that.

I gave only and all the bolded piecees of information, which besides for the ZIP code, approximate amount in my bank account, and name of the bank with which I have that account, were all yes/no questions. It seems like I didn't give them anything overly dangerous, but I am not versed in these matters.

Should I be worried about my assets, banking, or identity getting stolen?

Comment: This is an information security site, not a personal scam/fraud site. You should be working with the police.

Comment: My bad, I thought I remembered seeing others post similar things here before.

Answer (score 0):

As you've concluded, they don't have any information which they could use to actually make some financial damage **remotely** from what I see.

They know your:

- zip code
- bank name who issued the credit card (no transactional numbers)
- cash amount withheld with you
- vehicle

However, if they wanted to initiate a physical confrontation with you, they have all the necessary information to force you to hand them out the pin codes, cash, vehicle etc. considering that your assets spark interest in terms of money value.